# method alias in coffee script class - TypeError: Property is not a function

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I created a coffeeScript class with one method and its alias:

```
 class Class1
   method1 : (param1)=>
     console.log param1
   aliasForMethod1: @method1

 module.exports = Class1
```

It outputs javascript:

```
 // Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.2
    (function() {
      var Class1,
        __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };

      Class1 = (function() {
        function Class1() {
          this.method1 = __bind(this.method1, this);
        }

        Class1.prototype.method1 = function(param1) {
          return console.log(param1);
        };

        Class1.prototype.aliasForMethod1 = Class1.method1;

        return Class1;

      })();

      module.exports = Class1;

    }).call(this);
```

Try to use this class:

```
 Class1 = require './class1'

 instanceOfClass1 = new Class1()

 instanceOfClass1.method1()
 instanceOfClass1.aliasForMethod1()
```

But got error:

```
$ node /pathToMyClassUser/class1_user.js
undefined

 /pathToMyClassUser/class1_user.js:11
  instanceOfClass1.aliasForMethod1();
               ^
 TypeError: Property 'aliasForMethod1' of object #<Class1> is not a function
```

So **how to use alias** for method in coffeeScript class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is trying to refer to a nonexistent static method on `Class1` rather than its prototype. You can refer to the correct method like this (`this::` or `@::` is equivalent to `this.prototype.`, but shorter - thanks mu for the tip) :

```
class Class1
  method1 : (param1)=>
    console.log param1
  aliasForMethod1: @::method1
```

Or alternatively define `aliasForMethod1` as its own method that calls `method1`.

```
class Class1
  method1 : (param1)=>
    console.log param1
  aliasForMethod1: => @method1.apply(@, arguments)
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick, first variant seems to be simpler

Comment: I agree; I just came up with the second one first and thought I'd keep it in for completeness.

Comment: There's also `aliasForMethod1: @::method1` which has the same effect as the first one.

Comment: Be careful with `@::`.  That didn't work until recently due to a bug.

Comment: Is `this::` any different or was that similarly buggy?